# How to sync Redux actions among users when creating a live collaborative React.js application?

Tags: reactjs, redux, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I'm working on a "live" collaborative React.js application. The application's state is managed with Redux, and therefore I have a single application state object as well as a list of performed (dispatched) actions that result in each mutation in state.

Different users can "visit" the same instance of an application (by visiting a unique url with a GUID), i.e. the application state is shared. When a user performs an action, this action is send to a backend (AWS API Gateway > Lambda), which then stores the Action in dynamoDB and distributes it to other clients.

All connected clients then run the actions performed by the other users (after receiving them from the backend) since the latest "snapshot", such that ultimately all users' clients arrive at the same state. Note that a snapshot is simply a full copy of the app state at a certain timestamp, such that not all lifetime actions need to be executed for every instance, but only the actions since the latest snapshot.

This works fine. My only challenge is to correctly synchronize the order at which the different actions occurred. My idea was to transform each action's `createdAt` (could also be named `dispatchedAt`) timestamp on the server side to arrive at a timestamp that can be compared no matter the user's clock setting or timezone:

```
serverCreatedAt = serverNow - (clientNow - clientCreatedAt)
```

where `clientNow` is the timestamp on the client side when it submitted the action to the server, `clientCreatedAt` is the timestamp on the client side when it dispatched (created) the action, `serverNow` is the current timestamp on the server (i.e. it is reliable), and `serverCreatedAt` is the current server timestamp minus how long ago the action was dispatched.

While this approach seems to work in most cases, it is flawed because it does not consider latency: if client A's request took 2 seconds to arrive at the server, and client B's request took 0.5 seconds to arrive at the server, the transformed `serverCreatedAt` timestamps might indicate that client A's action was performed after client B's action even if it was not.

How do real-time collaborative systems usually deal with such issues where a client's clock cannot be trusted and network latency renders the time at which the action is received on the server-side unreliable?

Comment: I think you've answered your own question. Rely only on the server clock to identify the time an action was created, accepting some discrepancies (e.g. the fact that a user clicked a button 10ms before another user doesn't mean his action will be logged first).

Comment: So there is no better way, e.g. one that accounts for latency?

Comment: You could create a copy of the application state and specific user actions on each client and log actions locally. Then at some point merge them at the server and propagate changes as described here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=84zqbXUQIHc
https://hackernoon.com/building-conclave-a-decentralized-real-time-collaborative-text-editor-a6ab438fe79f